# can JPA eclipselink be mapped to REST service?

Tags: java, rest, persistence

Nowadays typical JAVA application can expose some JPA entities via REST easily. In that case in short there is e.g. persistence.xml where driver, database, etc are defined to access the database and persistence unit easily can be used in the application.

I am looking for something opposite. I.e. if somebody saw the solution where persistence relays on REST API?

Background of my question is the following.
There is an app written in some ancient technology and there is quite complex logic behind. I would like to build new JEE JPA (Eclipselink if possible) based application which could (at least for some time) use that complex logic in order to find and read data. My idea was to implement REST interface on top of old application and let the new one use REST queries in order to deal with the data. Since logic is complex I would like to avoid duplicating it and maintaining 2 branches of code in different technologies until I am fully prepared to move all stuff into modern technology.

Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can design your Data Access Layer and the rest of your new application so that it doesn't care how the data is stored (no "bad" dependencies).

You would then need to create separate versions of the DAL, where one would fetch the data from the legacy REST app and one would use JPA. This will make it possible to start out being dependent on the legacy app, and part by part build the JPA DAL to retrieve data from a database.